# Apache proxy pass is redirecting instead of acting like a real proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to hide the port of a deployed container and preserve the original url using ProxyPass.
I've probably missconfigured something because instead of simply keeping the original address I get a redirect to the container address (example.com:8014 instead of keeping subdomain.example.com). The HTTP response is: 301 Moved Permanently (from service worker).

This is the virtual host containing the proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain.example.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =subdomain.example.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName subdomain.example.com
        ServerAlias subdomain.example.com

        LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

        SSLProxyEngine On
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/privkey.pem

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / https://example.com:8014/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com:8014/
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the virtual host inside the container:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com:8014
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
        SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
        SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
        SSLSessionTickets       off
        SSLOptions +StrictRequire
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

The container ports are mapped as follow: 80->8012, 443->8014.

My goal is to reach example.com:8014 using subdomain.example.com without changing the address.
Also Im not even sure why when using example.com:8012 I'm not being redirected to https on port 8014.
The issue must be in the container virtual host because it's it that is generating the 301 status code.

Comment: Apparently it was google chrome fault. Somehow  it was caching the redirect while using edge it worked just fine. Wiping chrome cache fixed. That was very weird, especially because even in incognito mode the redirect was still cached.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration works just fine.
I would advice clearing google chrome's cache when something like this happens.